# Derivation of Magnetic Field from Infinite Wire

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, calculus

I'm trying to get my head around the derivation for the magnetic field of an infinite wire, in my notes I have the statement:
Setup: Wire centred on the z axis, current has direction +z.

"Biot-Savart: $\vec B$ perpendicular to $Id\vec l\implies B_z = 0$

How is this so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question, $Id\vec{l}$ is along the z-axis. If a vector is perpendicular to this vector it means that it has to lie in the plane perpendicular to it and cannot have a component in the z direction. Put in equations, Let
$$
\vec{B} = B_x \;\hat{x} + B_y\;\hat{y}+B_z\;\hat{z}
$$
Since $I\vec{dl}$ is along the z-axis, let,
$$
I\vec{dl} = I\;dl\; \hat{z}
$$
The dot product $I\vec{dl}\cdot \vec{B}=0$, thus,
$$
B_z\times I\;dl\; = 0 \implies B_z =0
$$
Which is the conclusion

Answer (score 0):

If the field is perpendicular to the $z$-axis, it can have $x$ and $y$ components but it cannot have a $z$ component.